# Change of name due to copyright, will new name work for SEO?

Tags: seo

A web hosting customer of mine has a domain, let's say it is `curlybumm.com`.  (These are examples that reasonably represent how it is playing out) The owners of a trademark `curly` have demanded she drop the name, they are in the same fashion category.

She has negotiated with them and they will allow `kerlybumm.com`.  Not ideal after getting a brand established, but so far so good.

Her question (via me)​ is about using something like "Curl~e bumm" in content and also used `curly` in meta.  From a search engine point of view (and customers being able to find her), would this would cause complications. SEO is a dark art to me :P

Comment: I thought she had to switch to "kerly"?   Would se be allowed to to use "curly" in meta?  That seems like a trademark infringement.   I'm not sure at all how "Curl~e" fits into this.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller me either, I think she is trying to push the limit of what she can do to stay on the right side of the TM owner and also keep the goodwill of her original name.

Comment: Is she able to keep and redirect the old domain name?   I rebranded due to a trademark (we owned the trademark somebody offered us more money than we could turn down to buy it) and we were able to keep the redirect in place for a year which really helped.

Comment: I have suggested to her that she (quietly) extends the domain for a couple of years and then negotiate to keep it and redirect until it expires - I would see that as a win.